# Why are DriveInfo's properties missing when serializing to json string using Json.NET?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, jsonserializer

Attempting to serialize DrivInfo to a Json string with this code only return the "name" property:

```
DriveInfo dr = new DriveInfo("C");    
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dr);
```

The string result is only:
`{"_name":"C:\"}`

DrivInfo is sealed so I cannot change anything. Is there a way to do it excluding wrapping?

Comment: Why would you serialize a type you don't control? What if MS decides to change the implementation of `DriveInfo`?

Comment: For internal utilisation in the company I wrote a program to dump information of the environment. So the objects are serialized then deserialized to xml files. I use serialized json string because of the limitation of XmlSerializer with default constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class contains its own custom serialization which specifies that only the `_name` field should be included. The other properties aren't stored in the class. They're determined by the environment, so they can't be replaced with deserialized values.

From the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/driveinfo.cs,5e187a6c915470e6):

```
private const String NameField = "_name";  // For serialization

    void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        // No need for an additional security check - everything is public.
        info.AddValue(NameField, _name, typeof(String));
    }
```

Other properties are determined by actually inspecting the drive referenced by the `DriveInfo`. Properties like `TotalFreeSpace` and `TotalFreeSize` can change from moment to moment and may not (probably don't) apply on another computer where the class could be deserialized.

If you *could* serialize the whole thing and deserialize it someplace else, then it would be possible to create a deserialized instance of the class where all of the property values are wrong, because, for example, they actually describe the `c:` drive on another computer. But the purpose of the class is to return information about a drive on the computer where the code is executing.

If you want to pass that data around then you can always create your own class and serialize that.

Answer (score 2):

Your difficulty is that [`DriveInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.aspx) implements the [`ISerializable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx) interface for custom  serialization, and Json.NET respects this interface by default, using it to serialize and deserialize the type.  And since `DriveInfo` is defined entirely by the name of the drive, that's all that it's custom serialization code stores into the serialization stream.

Since you just want to dump the properties of `DriveInfo` and do not care about deserialization, you can disable use of `ISerializable` by setting [`DefaultContractResolver.IgnoreSerializableInterface = true`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_IgnoreSerializableInterface.htm).  However, if you do this, you'll get an infinite recursion serializing [`dr.RootDirectory.Root.Root...`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.root.aspx).  To work around this, you could create a `JsonConverter` for `DirectoryInfo`:

```
public class DirectoryInfoConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(DirectoryInfo);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var token = JToken.Load(reader);
        return new DirectoryInfo((string)token);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Then you could do:

```
DriveInfo dr = new DriveInfo("C");
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings 
{ 
    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver { IgnoreSerializableInterface = true },
    Converters = new [] { new DirectoryInfoConverter() },
};
var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dr, Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

But at this point, it's probably easier just to serialize an intermediate anonymous type:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
    new
    {
        Name = dr.Name,
        DriveType = dr.DriveType,
        DriveFormat = dr.DriveFormat,
        IsReady = dr.IsReady,
        AvailableFreeSpace = dr.AvailableFreeSpace,
        TotalFreeSpace = dr.TotalFreeSpace,
        TotalSize = dr.TotalSize,
        RootDirectory = dr.RootDirectory.ToString(),
        VolumeLabel = dr.VolumeLabel
    },
    Formatting.Indented);
```

(Of course, you won't be able to deserialize it in this format.)