# How to serialize FileInfo object using NewtonSoft Json?

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I want to serialize `FileInfo` object using json.
Till now, I am getting below result upon serializing file info object using `JsonConvert.serializeOjbect()` method.

```
FileInfo finfo = new FileInfo("drive:\\folderpath\\file.txt");
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(finfo);
```

Of course, `finfo` holds a lot more properties than the two held by jsonString.
(Properties like `Exists`, `Directory`, `CreationTime`, `Extension`, `IsReadonly`, `LastAccessTime`, etc.)
`jsonstring` only holds two of these properties.

```
jsonString = {{
  "OriginalPath": "drive:\\folderpath\\file.txt",
  "FullPath": "drive:\\folderpath\\file.txt"
}}
```

**Is there a way to serialize whole object instead of these two properties using Json?**

Comment: Seems very similar to [Why are DriveInfo's properties missing when serializing to json string using Json.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37170011/why-are-driveinfos-properties-missing-when-serializing-to-json-string-using-jso/37170886#37170886).  Same approach should work also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason that you're only seeing those two properties is because `FileInfo` implements the `ISerializable` interface, and its `GetObjectInfo` method is being used to override the default serialization behavior.  If you had full control over the `FileInfo` class (which you don't) then you could apply the [JsonObject] attribute to force normal Json serialization behavior.

I think your only option in this case to write your own wrapper containing the properties that you want.  Your properties can just call the underlying `FileInfo` properties directly.